# C++ Creating a simple array of LPWSTR's

Tags: c++, windows, arrays, string, winapi

As a C++ noob, I can't seem to get this right even though I know it should be simple :{ - I need to create an array of LPWSTR and then populate it with unique strings. The idea was to do something simple like this:

```
LPWSTR *wszArray = new LPWSTR[5];

for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    swprintf(wszArray[x], "somestring_%d", x);
}
```

I know that I haven't allocated memory for the LPWSTR, but after trying a few things I am not having much luck. Also I'm not sure if the array should be free'd later once i'm done with the strings.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have right now is a single pointer to pointers to wide char. You're then initializing that with the address of an array of 5 dynamically allocated pointers to wide char's. That's fine as far as it goes, but does *not* allocate any space for the strings themselves, only for pointers to 5 strings. You then need to allocate space for the strings themselves:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    array[i] = new char[13];
    swprintf(array[i], L"somestring_%d", i);
}
```

Yes, you should delete the space you allocated after you're done using it. That would look something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    delete [] array[i];
delete [] array;
```

OTOH, you probably shouldn't do any of this, and instead use something like:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> array;

for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
     std::wostringstream temp;
     temp << L"somestring_" << i;
     array.push_back(temp.str());
}
```

In this case, you can retrieve a "LPWSTR" using `array[i].c_str()`. You don't have to allocate or free any of the memory explicitly at all though.

Comment: Format string should also be wide `swprintf(array[i], L"somestring_%d", i);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin Can you do that without having to use `wostringstream`?

Comment: @mk1: I can, but I see no good reason to do so. Why, do you see something terrible about `wostringstream`?

Comment: One obvious possibility: `for (int i=0; i<5; i++) array.push_back(std::wstring("somestring_" + std::to_wstring(i));`

Comment: For retrieving the value, array[i].str() didn't work for me, had to use array[i].c_str()

Answer (score 2):

actually `LPWSTR` is already a pointer you should rather do

```
LPTSTR pBuffer; // TCHAR* 
pBuffer = new TCHAR[128]; // Allocates 128 or 256 BYTES, depending on compilation.
```

and then the `for` loop will be fine.
for unicode-long string you need to prefix the string with
`L` like in  `L"your string"`

and later you need to free the memory allocated using `delete[]`

like :

```
delete[] pBuffer;
```

for further documentation you may like to read:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc

Comment: OP trying to allocate an array of wide strings

Comment: oh! my bad... then i think i would do pretty much what @Jerry Coffin
has posted

Answer (score 1):

LPWSTR is a unicode long string pointer in MS Windows, try using strings with the L"" form such as:

swprintf(wszArray[x], L"somestring_%d", x);

Unicode macros in Windows are available by using #define UNICODE, in MS VS there is a setting to use unicode strings, when set, it will define UNICODE for you.

LPWSTR is the same as wchar_t* and LPSTR is char*.

When allocate memory in c++, it should always be free'd, so the answer is Yes.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo - I was using L"" in my actual code. Allocation/deallocation is where I was stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Learning and doing some research-and-development is different aspect. But you shoulnt use these native methods for string processing. Instead use classes like `std::string`, `stringstream`, `CString` etc.

- `std::string` is used by many (NOT by me!), it doesn't support `<<`
  operator, nor formatting functions, but supports other functions.
- `stringstream` is rich, doesn't support formatting functions, but `<<` operators, which are resolved at compile time and are type-safe.
- `CString` supports formatting functions, and other common string functionality. It doesn't support `<<` operator. It handles ANSI/Unicode issues quite well. If you arent using MFC, you **still** can use it by `#include<atlstr.h>` in non-MFC project.

Comment: Sorry, the question was specifically for LPWSTR. I have my reasons for using it :)

Answer (score 0):

I am actually also new in C++ (only finish Deitel c++ book, nothing more), I like CString only :-( if I agree to allow the project to accept MFC library in the project settings, I include the whole library  in the header file if I feel like to, then I can do something like

```
CString str="";
CArray<CString,CString> arr;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{ 
   str.Format("something_%d",i);
   arr.Add(str);
}
```

If you really really love LPWSTR, the above also works with it. CString is a class designed to handle ANSi and Unixcode... :-)